# How do Alaskan bush pilots land and take off in 10'?

Tags: aerodynamics

How do Alaskan bush pilots land and take off in 10'?

Just looked at a video of the Valdeez STOL competition with pilot's taking off and landing in 10'

How do they do it? And no, they don't have a headwind of 40mph. Headwind is usually 10-15mph which is a pretty common scenario for all of us.

Comment: As far as I know, these bush plane videos involve considerable headwinds. With enough headwind, you can go all VTOL.

Comment: Fred, there is a problem in your last paragraph. If he is already stalled, or even partially stalled, pulling up won’t arrest the descent.

Comment: The scores for 2019 (https://docs.wixstatic.com/ugd/c3e139_f7c42bbf4cff4a96bd816ca18c5a4464.pdf) suggest that in competition it's closer to 100' not 10' (assuming the numbers are in feet and not something else).

Comment: There are different classes. 100' sounds it's like for one of the commercial aircraft classes. The world record is about 9.5'.... ( yes, that is in feet)  A normal Zenith701 can take off in 50', 25' in a good headwind....

Comment: This question should be reopened .....

Comment: References to specific planes and specific distances (and specific headwinds) would be nice.  A stock 172 doing a 10' takeoff in the calm would require a magical explanation.  A heavily modified (extra power, lower weight) airframe with a 20kt headwind doing the same seems tricky, but less remarkable.

Comment: A STOL competition is not "bush pilots" to me.

Comment: I'm told most of the participants are Alaskan bush plane pilots They just get together once a year to have a little fun, no different than a car or motorcycle meet.